# Long delay when sending ETH with MetaMask

Tags: metamask

I installed MetaMask (chrome) and added some ETH to my account. I then tried sending some ETH to an ICO. I sent 0.1 ETH and the transaction has been showing as "Contract Published" for the last few hours.

I assumed that it is because I used the wrong Gas Limit so I tried again (this time for 0.15 ETH). It has been almost 2 hours and I've not seen any change yet.

Can anyone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: can you post the full tx ID, please ?

Comment: You can get the tx id/hash by clicking one of the items on the list, btw.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a known MetaMask bug (that should be largely fixed later today).

The solution is probably to have your seed phrase backed up, then uninstall & reinstall MetaMask.

https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/USERS.md#slow-transactions